# How to prevent bounce of SMTPUTF8 emails

Tags: email, postfix

After updating postfix to 3.0, emails with UTF-8 chars in there subjects, are stuck in queue, with the following error:

> SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host mail.example.com
>   [1.2.3.4]

The receiving server (here called mail.example.com) are a postfix 2.10.1,
and doesn't support SMTPUTF8

How do I get postfix to send those emails?
Can I change some options in postfix, so it send it like it would have done before the update?

From my current options the interesting ones seem to be:

```
compatibility_level = 2
smtputf8_autodetect_classes = sendmail, verify
smtputf8_enable = ${{$compatibility_level} < {1} ? {no} : {yes}}
strict_smtputf8 = no
```

I think all of those settings are the default once in 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Postfix [README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html#detecting):

> By default, Postfix sets the "SMTPUTF8 requested" flag only on address
>   verification probes and on Postfix sendmail submissions that contain
>   UTF-8 in the sender address, UTF-8 in a recipient address, or UTF-8 in
>   a message header value.

If you submit mail through sendmail command or use address verification you may have to tweak `smtputf8_autodetect_classes` option.

To successfully flush the queue, after correcting `smtputf8_autodetect_classes` option, all mails have to be requeued with `postsuper -r ALL` command. Temporary disabling of `smtputf8` feature may also be needed (see discussion in comments).

Comment: the queued emails come from apache/php, and I think its delivered to postfix by the sendmail command.

I played a bit with smtputf8_autodetect_classes, but it dosn't seams to ffect the emails alredy in queue.

Comment: Maybe you could disable smtputf8 temporarily (`smtputf8_enable = no`) and flush the queue? Haven't tried this though.

Comment: have tested `postconf -e smtputf8_enable=no`, `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`, `postqueue -f`, but they still stays in the queue

Comment: Try to requeue the emails with `postsuper -r`  (with smtputf8 disabled). Test first with single `id`, before you go with `ALL`.

Comment: Requeue with `smtputf8_enable = no` and `smtputf8_autodetect_classes = bounce` worked, the bounce should proberly be off or no, but just took a value other then sendmail to get it to work. Add the requeue info to you answer and il mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @PugganSe Updated. I believe that with smtputf8 disabled the autodetect option doesn't have any effect. Also resubmiting mails to queue is different than submitting through sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this bug this morning.

- When an email was sent with "php", I received :

```
X-Postfix; SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host
    mx-aol.mail.gm0.yahoodns.net[67.195.204.80]
```

- When an email was sent to same adress with a proper mailer, the mail was received.

So instead of fixing "postfix", I fixed my php `mail()` command.

This is what worked for me, hope this helps someone.

```
                mail (  // $to =
                        $row["email"],
                        // $subject =
                        "Email subject here",
                        // $message =
                        quoted_printable_encode ("Bonjour,\r\n\r\nBlah blah - Sentiments distingués ... etc. "),

// $headers =
                        'From: ****@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'Reply-To: *******@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
                        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .  // <--- this is THE part.
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/example.com');
```